# Ionic android build Error - Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable

Tags: android, linux, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to build android for ionic in linux but its showing me an error like this

```
     [Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. 
      Try setting setting it manually.
      Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. 
      Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.]
      ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/kumar/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
      You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
      Error: /home/kumar/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

and i've added this in my bashrc file

```
export ANT_HOME="/usr/bin/ant"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin"
export HOME="/home/kumar"
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/android-sdk-linux/tools"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="$HOME/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS:$PATH"
```

I'm thinking i've given the path but i dont know why its showing me this error .. Please help....

Comment: Are you using ubuntu system:?

Comment: Please follow this tutorial [link](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/install-android-cordova-ionic-framework-ubuntu/) It will be helpful for you, I have followed this tutorial only for installing Ionic framework

Comment: Have you checked the link?

Comment: now i'm checking it. thanks.. Hope it works..

Comment: Hmm welcome, I will write that answer please accept and upvote it

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Android Home should be the root folder of SDK.

```
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/android-sdk-linux"
```

**EDIT**:  Open terminal and type these commands. (yes, on a ternimal , not in bashrc file)

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/android-sdk-macosx
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

and then in the same terminal just type `android`. If configured you would be able to use build commands from this terminal. (it's a temporary solution)

Comment: changed it but still getting the same issue.

Comment: try doing `source ~/.bashrc` at your terminal.

Answer (score 14):

### For OSX

- into **~/.bash_profile** add:

  ```
  export ANDROID_HOME="/path/to/android-sdk-macosx"
  export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH"
  ```

  and then execute it in terminal to take effect immediately;
- into **/etc/sudoers** add: (you can use console: `sudo visudo`)

  ```
  Defaults        env_keep += "ANDROID_HOME"
  ```

  since the building process has to start with `sudo` and Node's `process.env` get the respective variables.

Answer (score 9):

Case: using SO Windows, try:

```
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\\android-sdk-windows
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

more in: http://spring.io/guides/gs/android/

Case: you don't have platform-tools:

```
cordova platforms list
cordova platforms add <Your_platform, example: Android>
```

Answer (score 9):

## Setup for Linux/Ubuntu/Mint

1. download [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) or SDK only
2. [install](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html)
3. set PATH

### 3.1) Open terminal and edit `~/.bashrc`

```
sudo su
vim ~/.bashrc
```

### 3.2) Export ANDROID_HOME and add folders with binaries to your PATH

Common default install folders:

- /root/Android/Sdk
- ~/Android/Sdk

Example `.bashrc`

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/root/Android/Sdk
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

### 3.3) Refresh your PATH

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

### 4) Install correct SDK

> When `ionic build android` still fails it could be because of wrong
>   sdk version. To install correct versions and images run `android` from
>   command line. Since it is now in your PATH you should be able to run
>   it from anywhere.

Comment: For me, it was installed as my current user, so replace `/root` with `~`

Answer (score 6):

Download the android SDK
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

You only export the path of SDK folder.

`export ANDROID_HOME="YOUR_PATH/sdk/"`

Answer (score 6):

The procedure is already well explained in the above answers. But if add the `ANDROID_HOME` and `PATH` to the `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` present in `/home/username/` and try to run the `ionic` command with `sudo`, you may get this error again.

The reason is, it may look for the `ANDROID_HOME` and `PATH` in the `.zshrc` file of root user instead of currently logged in user. So you shouldn't do that unless you add that in root user's `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` files.

Comment: Almost 1 hour I wasted setting .bashrc again and again without knowing this need to set in root user bashrc. thanks stranger

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem when running `sudo ionic run android` as root as these environmental variables were not persisted. Fixed by running `sudo -E ionic run android`.

Comment: Thanks @D_plus_plus but what causes the issue

Answer (score 3):

Windows -  set environment variable permanently:

> setx ANDROID_HOME "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk"

or

> setx ANDROID_HOME "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"

Answer (score 2):

You only have to edit your profile file like this:

```
sudo su
vim ~/.profile
```

and put this at the end of the file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/(user name)/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/platform-tools
```

Save and close the file and do:

```
cd ~
source .profile
```

now if you do:

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

it should show you something like this:

```
/home/(user name)/Android/Sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

## For OSX

Great tutorial here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kY22NSBwV_s

No need to do any bash commands/symlinks:

1. Install Java 6 runtime: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=de_DE
2. Install Java JDK: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 0):

In my Case: I have put the correct path for Android and java but still getting the error.

The problem was that I have added the Android platform using sudo command.`sudo ionic cordova platform android`.

**To solve my problem:**
First I have removed the platform android by running command

> sudo ionic cordova platform rm android

then add the android platform again with out sudo`ionic cordova platform add android`
but i get the error of permissions.

To resolve the error run command

> sudo chmod -R 777 {Path-of-your-project}

in my case `sudo chmod -R 777 ~/codebase/IonicProject`

Then run command

> ionic cordova platform add android

or

> ionic cordova run android

Answer (score 0):

To add ANDROID_HOME value **permanently**,

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

and add the following lines

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/root/Android/Sdk
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

Save the file and you need not update ANDROID_HOME value everytime.