# :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental

Tags: java, android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to setup Ionic on my new machine but I have ran into a problem with building a Cordova Android project, that I cannot seem to fix. 
The programs and versions I use are:

- NodeJS   `v6.9.1`
- npm      `v3.10.8`
- Cordova  `v6.4.0`
- Ionic    `v1.3.22`
- Apache Ant `1.9.7`
- Windows  `7 SP1`

For building I use Java 8:

- JAVA_HOME: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112`
- Java version: `1.8.0_112`

For building my android project I use SDK version `21 (5.0.1)`

I have created an Ionic started project via the command: `ionic start test tabs` and didn't change any code of the project.

---

**The errror**

While using the command `ionic build android` I get the error `:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).`

---

**What I tried**

I Tried running [running cordova update and after that ionic build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35880231/ionic-build-android-cordovalibcompiledebugjavawithjavac) -  **This did not work.**

After that I tried using an other java jdk version (`1.8.0_45`). The setup on my old machine was working with this version. I also changed the JAVA_HOME variable with this attempt. **Unfortunately I had no luck with this attempt.**

On multiple topics it is suggested to use JDK 8, because JDK 7 is not compatible with android versions 21 and up. But I get this error while using JDK 8 so that **doesn't solve my problem.**

I tried removing the android platform and readd it. **That also did not solve my problem**. It gave me the same error message.

---

**Additional information**

Adding the Android platform via the Ionic command `ionic platform add android@5.0.1` gives me an error. It does not know that version number (but according to Android SDK manager 5.0.1 = android 21).

Using `ionic platform add android@5.0.0` gives me android version 23. So that does not work either.

Because of the problems above I manually changed the version numbers in the Android platform. I changed the version number to `21` on the following places:

- test\platforms\android --> AndroidManifest.xml
- test\platforms\android --> project.properties
- test\platforms\android\CordovaLib --> project.properties

I have had no problem before with changing the version numbers before.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Update your JRE and JDK and IONIC as well.

Comment: This is the newest version of Ionic before 2.0 and I don't want to use Ionic 2. Also this is the newest JRE & JDK version.

Comment: updating ionic to version 2 will cause no effects on your current projects.

Comment: You are right about that, but that doesn't solve this issue since I am using this ionic version on my old machine, which works?

Comment: I tried it anyway, but unfortunately still have the same error.

Comment: may be because you were using old versions of cordova, nodejs and other thing so this version of ionic worked fine for you.